# HBase [ERROR]: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess - Cannot get replica 0 location for

Tags: java, hbase, talend

I have this error when I try to load data into my HBase table with my Talend Job:

```
[ERROR]: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess - Cannot get replica 0 location for {"totalColumns":2,"families":{"0":[{"timestamp":1525346138064,"tag":[],"qualifier":"CURRENT_VALUE","vlen":8},{"timestamp":1525346138064,"tag":[],"qualifier":"LIMIT_REACHED_FLAG","vlen":1}]},"row":"\\x8B\\x00EXABEAT_DISPATCHER\\x00ID_LOG_DETTAGLIO"}
```

I need to understand why this error appeared.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The causes can vary, but generally this indicates an issue with the `ZooKeeper` instance used by the HBase cluster or an issue with communicating with the HBase processes which clients use to get the region assignment.  There does not appear to be documentation on this topic.